# Creating A Cube Using Only CSS Gradients

Tags: html, css, graphics, 3d

I've tried numerous ways using linear-gradients to create several stripes layered on top of each other and have gotten very close but seem to be stuck on the top face.  I'm trying to accomplish this using gradients be it linear or radial so that I can eventually upgrade them to repeating gradients and have a nice background of cubes. I'm applying css to an empty body tag. I think it might actually be impossible, somebody please prove me wrong! This is the perspective i was going for:

```
 / \
|\ /|
| | | 
 \ /
```

Comment: You need 3 HTML divs for that.

Comment: i wish to do it without any extra elements besides the one i'm applying the css to, in my case the body element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, i fingered it out myself!

```css
#cube
{
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    background:
        linear-gradient(45deg, 
            black 0%, 
            black 43%, 
            transparent 43%, 
            transparent 60%, 
            black 60%, 
            black 100%
        ), 
        linear-gradient(-45deg, 
            black 0%, 
            black 43%, 
            transparent 43%, 
            transparent 60%, 
            black 60%, 
            black 100%
        ), 
        linear-gradient(90deg, 
            black 0%, 
            black 44%, 
            transparent 44%, 
            transparent 56.5%, 
            black 56.5%, 
            black 100%
        ), 
        linear-gradient(45deg, 
            transparent 0%, 
            transparent 50%, 
            rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.388235) 50%, 
            rgba(150, 0, 0, 0.388235) 100%
        ), 
        linear-gradient(-45deg, 
            transparent 0%, 
            transparent 50%, 
            rgb(255, 0, 0) 50%, 
            rgb(255, 0, 0) 100%
        ), 
        linear-gradient(90deg, 
                rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%, 
                rgb(255, 0, 0) 50%, 
                rgb(150, 0, 0) 50%, 
                rgb(150, 0, 0) 100%
        ), 
        black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="cube"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the `before` and `after` pseudo-element to get the 3D cube effect. Here is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
                margin: 20px;
                background: red;
            }
            div::before {
                display: block;
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                width: 71px;
                height: 102px;
                background: green;
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg) translateX(-24px) translateY(96px) skewY(45deg);
            }
            div::after {
                display: block;
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                width: 72px;
                height: 100px;
                background: blue;
                -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateX(100px) translateY(36px) skewY(45deg);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi for creating a cube using css you must have to define the perspective width for box, and then rotate it to a certain angle to get its look.
here you may find how create a css cube
[CSS 3D Cube](https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-3d-cube-image-gallery/)
and here you may learn how Perspective property works
[Perspective](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/),
Hope it will help.

Comment: that article uses multiple html elements to create the faces of the cube. I want to use only css to create all the faces.

Comment: if you do not want to use scss, than compile it and use the pure css, online compliers you may get like http://sassmeister.com/